# Get desktop path with groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm automating a SoapUI project with Groovy that generate and excel report at the end with the results of my requests.

My problem is that I want to get the desktop path in which the file will be saved.

Something similar to this java code, but in Groovy :

```
String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you want the Desktop path or the path where the file will be saved which must not be in the Desktop folder?  For the second one you can show us how you save the excel?

Comment: Is your code not working in Groovy? What is the error? The code you show should be perfectly valid Groovy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your desktop path in *Groovy* you can use your *Java* code directly, since it works perfectly:

```
String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
```

If you want an alternative a *Groovy* way to do so could be:

```
String userHomeFolder = System.properties['user.home'] + "/Desktop"
```

Or:

```
String userHomeFolder = System.properties.'user.home' + "/Desktop"
```

All of this gets the same result.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @HamzaAmami nice to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Groovier way:

```
String userHomeFolder = "${System.properties.'user.home'}/Desktop"
```

you might also want to use a propper `File.separator`, but even with a mix of `/` and `\` is should work fine